# J2ME-recordstore

Tags: java-me

Can someone please tell me what does `recordenumertaion` return when word being searched is not present in `recordstore`?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that if there are no records to return, the method **enumerateRecords** returns an empty **RecordEnumeration**. That is, **hasNextElement** will return false the first time you call it. I guess it *could* return null, or throw an exception, but [the documentation](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/) doesn't mention those, so empty enumeration it seems to be.

Don't be afraid to read the docs!